# Find Value in multiple columns

Tags: excel

My reference table is in the following format 
`ID Year V1 V2`.

My current table to be filled is a table intersection format. Each column header is Year and Value1 and Value2 is below the Year.

Is there any functions that can help me return the value in the reference table to the current table?

```
>Reference table

>ID     Year    V1            V2
>10683  2   0.531026    -0.79178
>10683  3   1.008127    -1.077169
>10683  4   0.955959    -0.964647
>10683  5   0.558926    -0.877043
>10683  6   0.49269     -1.083005   
>10683  7   0.681587    -0.783695   
>10683  8   -0.006625   -0.849351   
>10683  9   0.114296    -0.412681   
>10683  10  0.149242    -0.449778   
>11165  2   0.651877    -0.96499    
>11165  3   0.959761    -1.428059   
>11165  4   0.669888    -1.561034   
>11165  5   0.315704    -1.275352   
>11165  6   0.382365    -0.947102   


Current Table
        2           2           3           3
ID      V1          V2          V1          V2
10683   0.531026    -0.791781   1.008127    -1.077169
11165   0.651877    -0.96499    0.959761    -1.428059
11298   1.019337    -0.769759   1.528429    -0.740333
11306   0.160293    0.870783    1.40843     1.48483
12257   0.599724    0.426487    1.048529    0.520844
```

Comment: If there is single combination of ID, Year & version, even PivotTable should suffice. Have you tried that?

Comment: Actual @Nimesh has it correct, A Pivot table is a better answer than my formula.

Comment: @Nimesh Yes, that works! great, thank you!

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried your formula and ctrl+shift+entered I got n/a.

Comment: As this futile in that a Pivot table is better but, Did you ensure that the references are pointing to the correct data?  And that you were in edit mode at the time you hit ctrl-shift-enter.  I promise I did not photo shop the picture.

Comment: lol. i trust you. I probably mess up the reference. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I Set up the table so you can reference to where the formula points:

[image]

The formula I used:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(B$19,IF($A$1:$A$15 = $A21,$B$1:$B$15),0),MATCH(B$20,$A$1:$D$1,0)))
```

This is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with ctrl-shift-Enter.

You will need to set up the headers and ID.  But then I added the formula in B21.  Confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then dragged it over and down.

Comment: How is it this if work? return the year when we find the ID? IF($A$1:$A$15 = $A21,$B$1:$B$15)

Comment: That will not return what you want.  You will need to use the small function to get the list.